# Validate YAML sequence with hibernate validator against enum

Tags: java, yaml, hibernate-validator

I am trying to create my own validator for validating a `List<String>` read from a YAML configuration file. What I want to do, is validate it against a Enum class that I have created which looks like the following:

```
public enum BundleName {
    DK("dk.bundle"),
    UK("uk.bundle"),
    US("us.bundle"),
    DK_DEBUG("dk.bundle.debug"),
    UK_DEBUG("uk.bundle.debug"),
    US_DEBUG("us.bundle.debug"),
    ;

    private String bundleName;

    BundleName(String bundleName) {
        this.bundleName = bundleName;
    }

    public String getBundleName() {
      return this.bundleName
    }
}
```

My YAML file has the following defined:

```
bundleNames:
  - ${DK}
  - ${UK}
  - ${US}
  - ${DK_DEBUG}
  - ${UK_DEBUG}
  - ${US_DEBUG}
```

Now either some of these environment variables might be set or all of them might be set or just one is set. Different environment different combo. Anyway what I want is to be able to validate these environment variables against the `bundleName` in enum `BundleName.class`. Now Hibernate have a nice [example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-class-level-constraints), and also all other examples I find on the net is, where validation is done against a specific simple enum. I do not want to check on the enum name but the enum value, and I simply cannot figure out how. All what I have tried so fare is some combinations of what I found in some other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation) and many more.

In my `ApiConfiguration.java` I would like to end up with something like the following on my list read from YAML:

```
@NotNull
@BundleNameValidation(acceptedValues = BundleName.class)
private List<String> bundleNames;
```

If that is possible somehow.

Comment: The approaches you linked should be capable of doing what you want. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @flyx I have tried several combinations of the linked approaches also exactly the same approches on a `List<String>` but the linked approcahes do the validation on a single String field which is not of my interest. The only thing I have not tried which might work is defining the values as they do like for example `@MyValidator(MyEnum.STRING)` or `@MyValidator(accpectedValues={MyEnum.VALUE1, MyEnum.VALUE2}`. This approach is not desirable  as I would have to add this to my validator each time I add a new Enum value. I am trying a new approach currently, if I find a solution I will post it.