# adding a constraint to spring entity set field value to one of possible predefined values

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

good day everyone,

i'm currently working on a spring application for school project, it's about a form generator. anyway i have a question entity which has a field called type, i want that field to be one of 3 different values (radio which is the default, checkbox, or input) but i didn't know how to do this with hibernate annotations or even with the spring constraints annotations so i was hoping someone here has an idea on how to do this.

thanks for your time everyone and hope you have a nice day.

Comment: Use an enum. That's what they're for.

Comment: you can make use of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070806/10664446)

Comment: ok thanks i'll try those answers