# mongodb + springboot. How to do extensive filtering?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My account.java is this

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Document(collection="Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
}
```

my repo for it is this

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, Integer> {

}
```

Finally. For my controller  (not done yet)

```
@PutMapping("/createAccount")
public void createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {

}
```

I want the following,

If I were to send a json in the request body such as

```
{
    "username": "Tom",
    "password": "123456",
    "role": "Employee"
}
```

Then it would make an object in the Account collection with that property which can easily be done through repository.insert(account). However I need to check certain filters

1. All 3 objects needs to be set
2. role must be either "Employee", "Admin", or "Customer"
3. Lastly user isn't already in the database

Otherwise sends Response 400

How do I achieve this with springboot?

Comment: for 1 and 2 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation for 3 you have to do it manuallym by reading into database

Comment: > for 3 you have to do it manuallym by reading into database - how?

Comment: Add a repository method 'findByUserName' and pass the user name . Check if the result is empty only the. Proceed with save

Comment: okay that works but is there a list of these commands? Additionally, if you know, how would I accomplish custom queries? For example, db.getCollection("Account").find({"username":"bob123"}) (I know this can easily be done with these custom methods just using it as an example)

Comment: @bob for custom queries https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query
There are also default queries provided by the @ Repository annotation.
Example of queries provided by spring boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use @Valid Annotation in the Controller then you can put either @NotNull or @NotEmpty or @NotBlank in your Model class. Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

public void createAccount(@Valid @RequestBody Account account) {

}

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private String role;
}
```

2. You can use Spring Security Expressions. Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic

   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")

   @PutMapping("/createAccount")

   public void createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {

   }