# Do we have any best approach to check or validate values of a field in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, enums, annotations

I have around 500 fields where I need to check values coming for the fields from json in spring rest endpoint are having valid values

ex:

```
Class Customer {

    long id;

    String gender; // acceptable values: MALE || FEMALE 

    int validated; // acceptable values: 0 || 1

    String plan;// acceptable values: PLAN1 || PLAN2 || PLAN3 || PLAN4

}
```

it will be harder to write a custom method to check each field, is there any generic approach where we dont need to write method validations for each field or class.

I have tried this [Java String validation using enum values and annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation)
but this is not throwing error when the value is not in the acceptable values. Basically it should be throwing exception if value is other than acceptable value

Comment: I think you simply want to test your Json against [a Json Schema](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java), throwing an exception if the validation collects one or multiple messages (with the exception containing the validation result). P.s. I have been using [this validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) and it's very powerful.

Comment: why don't you just use real enum value for string?